# How to contract geojson polygon

Tags: polygon, geojson, turf

I'd like to convert the big red area to a smaller one (blue) by shifting their borders parallelly by a certain distance to inner direction. This is not equivalent to **scale** as the result shape will look different.

Do you know an existing out-of-the-box function for contract? I tried to find one e.g. on [turf](http://turfjs.org/) but I did not manage to.

[image: contract]

Comment: That's a *buffer* with a negative value. Sorry, no time for a proper answer right now, could you do that?

Comment: See http://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer, negative values are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Awesome guys, thanks for the answers. [Buffer](https://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer) works like a charm:

```
import buffer from '@turf/buffer'
import { polygon } from '@turf/helpers'

...

buffer(polygon([[[lng1, lat1], [lng2, lat2], ... ]]), -3, { units: 'kilometers' })
```